# gilab-ci.yaml - Unable to run Nunit tests with dotnet

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab-ci

Here is my gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - dotnet restore ./WorldServer.sln

release:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/release/WorldServer.exe
  script:
    # The output path is relative to the position of the csproj-file
    - dotnet build .\WorldServer.sln
    
debug:
  stage: test
  script:
    # The output path is relative to the position of the csproj-file
    - dotnet test ./WorldServer.sln
```

Here is the output when the runner executes:

```
 Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.1 (6fbc7474)
   on codescarsgaming gM7RAymZ
Preparing the "docker" executor
 Using Docker executor with image microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
 Pulling docker image microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
 Using docker image sha256:156e5cc5d7a3aaf4166d17f1e0b3a3c262a22caf8efac9b855ba1782ef98071c for microsoft/dotnet:latest ...
Preparing environment
00:03
 Running on runner-gm7raymz-project-2-concurrent-0 via codescarsgaming...
Getting source from Git repository
00:05
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/ScarsOfHonor/Server/.git/
 Checking out 74c78e7e as master...
 Removing WorldServer.Tests/obj/WorldServer.Tests.csproj.nuget.cache
 Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:14
 $ dotnet restore ./WorldServer.sln
   Restore completed in 4.3 sec for /builds/ScarsOfHonor/Server/WorldServer.Tests/WorldServer.Tests.csproj.
 $ dotnet test ./WorldServer.sln
 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.807/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/builds/ScarsOfHonor/Server/WorldServer.Tests/WorldServer.Tests.csproj]
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it?